# Does ViewContainerRef.clear() remove component from memory?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

When I create a component using `ViewContainerRef` and assign instance to a property of parent component, which is responsible for child component creation, do I need to set this property to `null` after I call `ViewContainerRef.clear()` if I want memory to be freed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, if you assign parent component property to `componentRef` angular won't remove component from memory.

Angular only destroys component and removes its own references to this component. But reference to componentRef remains to live in your component property. So i would assign `null` to it. This way garbage collect will be able to clear memory

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/T1vHbE8B00a5bTckbksS?p=preview)** (add => clear => check)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="addComponent()">Add component</button>
      <div #container></div>
      <button (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
      <button (click)="check()">check</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  comp: ComponentRef<DynamicComponent>;

  constructor(
     private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, 
     private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  addComponent() {
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);
    this.comp = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);
  }

  clear() {
    this.vcRef.clear();
  }

  check() {
    alert(this.comp);
  }
}
```

See also

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100% sure but Angular calls ngOnDestroy() method of dynamically created components when their parent component is removed by Router.

here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/rAX6745xZi6EvP8N78IL?p=preview

```
import {Component, NgModule,Injector, ComponentFactoryResolver, 
TemplateRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {Routes, RouterModule, Route} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-other',
  template: `<div>other</div>`
})
export class Other {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-cmp',
  template: `<div>
     my cmp 
     <ng-content></ng-content>
   </div>
   `
})
export class MyComp {
  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('dynamic component ngOnDestroy is called');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
     <a routerLink="/viewchild">go viewchild</a>
     <a routerLink="/other">go other</a>
     <div>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </div>
     `
})
 export class App {}    

@Component({
  selector: 'my-prt',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="create()">Create</button>

       <div #vc>
          <my-cmp>static one</my-cmp>
       </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Parent {
  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;
  cmpRef = [];

  constructor(private injector: Injector, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  create() {
    const projectableNodes = [[document.createTextNode('a'), document.createTextNode('b')]];
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComp);
    this.cmpRef.push(this.vc.createComponent(factory, this.injector, undefined, projectableNodes);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
     //this.cmpRef.forEach(ref=>ref=null);
  }
}

let routes = [
  {path:'viewchild', component: Parent},
  {path:'other', component: Other}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes ],
  declarations: [ App, MyComp, Parent, Other ],
  entryComponents: [MyComp],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```